# Ajax request fails in Meteor but is correct in localhost test

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, meteor

I try to get some data from my MySql db. I have 2 files:

```
// client/book.js 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnJSonDB").bind("click", function () {

            var request = $.ajax({
                url: "book.php",
                type: "GET",   
                data: "",    
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",    
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            }); //end ajax  
            request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);
           });
        }); //end click
    }); //end ready
```

and server side:

```
// server/book.php 
$db = new mysqli(DATA_HOST,DATA_UTENTE,DATA_PASS,DATA_DB );
$select = "SELECT * FROM bk_book";
$strJSon = "{\"book\":{}}";
$query = @mysqli_query($db,$select);
if( $query )  {
    $result = [];
    while($result[] = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
    @mysqli_close($db);
    $strJSon = "{\"book\":" . json_encode($result) . "}";
}
echo $strJSon;
```

I try in my localhost space (windows-xampp) and all it's ok, In meteor I recive an error message:

```
Parse error
```

I try to comment datatype (json problem?) and I see the html page without my data.

The result is a correct json format:

```
{  
   "book":[  
      {  
         "nrent":"xxxxxx",
         "start_date":"2017-01-05",
         "end_date":"2017-01-12",
         "user_ID":"15",
         "booking_status":"estimate",
         "note":"",
         "adults_numb":"0",
         "children_numb":"0",
         "booking_bill":"630.00",
         "name":"Camera Bi",
         "first_name":"dddd",
         "last_name":"ddd",
         "mail":"dddd@dddd.it",
         "telephone":"ddddddd"
      },
      {  
         "nrent":"fffff",
         "start_date":"2017-01-08",
         "end_date":"2017-01-27",
         "user_ID":"25",
         "booking_status":"active",
         "note":"",
         "adults_numb":"2",
         "children_numb":"0",
         "booking_bill":"1710.00",
         "name":"Camera Ba",
         "first_name":"pippo",
         "last_name":"puppo",
         "mail":"fff@pippfffo.it",
         "telephone":"ffffff"
      },
      {  
         "nrent":"aaaaa",
         "start_date":"2017-01-28",
         "end_date":"2017-02-01",
         "user_ID":"24",
         "booking_status":"estimate",
         "note":"",
         "adults_numb":"0",
         "children_numb":"0",
         "booking_bill":"380.00",
         "name":"Camera Ba",
         "first_name":"ffff",
         "last_name":"wwww",
         "mail":"no@email.it",
         "telephone":""
      },
      null
   ]
}
```

I try the https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and is correct

Comment: it seems like your json result format is invalid.

Comment: In my localhost test it return a perfect object with correct data

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35522734/settings-json-parse-error-reading-settings-file

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = new mysqli(DATA_HOST,DATA_UTENTE,DATA_PASS,DATA_DB );
$select = "SELECT * FROM bk_book";
$jsonObject = new stdclass();

$query = @mysqli_query($db,$select);
if( $query )  {
    $result = [];
    while($result[] = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
    @mysqli_close($db);
    $jsonObject->book = $result;
}
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", true);
echo json_encode($jsonObject);
```

Comment: what output you get if you hit the book.php in url ? *edited my answer*

Comment: In my localhost in console.log i see a perfect object with all my data, problem is in meteor response

Comment: Have you tried with header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", true); in the above code.

Comment: For me it's impossible to get data from a Meteor local php api, I put my php in a web site and all is correct (??????)